# Can't log into GitLab Web UI via Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, centos, gitlab

I've been trying to get GitLab set up on a CentOS 7 server I have running on my local network so I have somewhere to store and sync my files and projects during the upcoming semester. I followed the install instructions for the omnibus package installation found [here](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#centos-7).

Now, after setting it up, I was unable to log in as the root user. I've since found that I can use Microsoft Edge to authenticate, but Google Chrome doesn't work. I've asserted that the behavior is similar regardless of whether I access the site via IP or address(locally-assigned in the router DNS server). When I try to log in using Chrome, the web application hangs, perpetually loading.

I've used gitlab-ctl to check NGINX's logs and it looks like the POST request simply isn't going through when I use chrome. Here's some sample output:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
192.168.1.52 - - [18/Aug/2019:18:15:47 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 98 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
192.168.1.52 - - [18/Aug/2019:18:15:57 -0600] "POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 302 85 "http://192.168.1.2/users/sign_in" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
192.168.1.52 - - [18/Aug/2019:18:15:57 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8684 "http://192.168.1.2/users/sign_in" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
192.168.1.52 - - [18/Aug/2019:18:16:03 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8673 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
192.168.1.52 - - [18/Aug/2019:18:16:06 -0600] "GET /users/sign_out?nav_source=navbar HTTP/1.1" 302 97 "http://gitlab.lan/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
192.168.1.52 - - [18/Aug/2019:18:16:06 -0600] "GET /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 200 4718 "http://gitlab.lan/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
192.168.1.52 - - [18/Aug/2019:18:16:12 -0600] "POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 302 84 "http://gitlab.lan/users/sign_in" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
```

I've tried clearing browsing history/cache/cookies in hopes that it would sort out something that may have gotten stuck while I was configuring GitLab, but nothing has seemed to help. I should mention that I've only opened port 80 via firewalld, not port 443. I plan to run GitLab over only HTTP. Microsoft Edge's success in accessing and authenticating with the site indicates to me that configuring GitLab this way shouldn't be an issue.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

I'm running `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`, `GitLab Version 12.1.6-ee Revision d05ee0a9c12`, and `Google Chrome 76.0.3809.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing a similar issue, I've found the cause:

The top-level domain of `gitlab.lan`, `.lan`, is not registered among the [IANA's TLD database](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db). Apparently, some browsers won't allow certain types of connections(in this case Chrome didn't allow the POST method) to domains if the domain is not an official TLD.

Now, in my question, I said access via IP wasn't working either. I believe that issue was caused when I configured GitLab, specifying the domain it would be attached to as `gitlab.lan`. I expect that GitLab was rendering links to itself using that address. This way, it would try to POST to `gitlab.lan` whether the user accessed the site via IP or domain.

**The solution was to use a valid TLD instead of `.lan` for the website domain(`.com`, `.net`, etc...).**

Regarding which browsers validate domain TLDs  before accessing a website, Chrome seems to be hit and miss and Edge seems to not validate at all. Mileage seems to vary and I expect the behavior to be undefined or change regularly, so I won't document which browsers behave which way here.